# Router serving as DMZ host at the same time

Tags: router, port-forwarding, dmz

My Linksys EA6700 wireless router supports DMZ. To configure DMZ I need to specify a DMZ host.

As far as I understand, the DMZ host is a server which can be accessed from the Internet. As I have a hard disk attached to the router which I want to access, I expected to use the Linksys router as the server.

However, it's not possible to select it from the list. Entering the IP manually gives error 2299, details are

```
/jnap/firewall/SetDMZSettings
Status: 200 OK 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
Connection: close 
Content-Length: 48 
Date: Wed, 08 Jan 2014 18:10:58 GMT 
Server: lighttpd/1.4.28
```

Is it a general concept that the router cannot be the DMZ host or might this be a bug of the Linksys EA6700 router?

**Update**

From the comments, it seems not a good idea to expose the router directly.
As the EA6700 also provides port forwarding, would that be more secure?

Comment: While not specific to your router, per-se... the principle still applies.  By putting your disk in a DMZ, guarded by a linksys, I think you trust your linksys [more than I would](http://blog.spiderlabs.com/2013/05/under-the-hood-linksys-remote-command-injection-vulnerabilities.html).  I'm not singling out linksys individually, rather that too many consumer network devices are vulnerable to remote exploits.  In general, I personally wouldn't expose any sensitive data behind them to the internet.

Comment: Oh, it's not sensitive data that I want to put onto the disk. Just large files which are too large for my webspace. This way, users can download the content at slow speed, but better than not downloading at all. Of course, a remote shell injection would not be good :-(

Comment: Putting your router in the DMZ will also expose the router configuration page to the Internet.  That, I'm assuming, is sensitive data, since it controls your network configuration.

Comment: Is [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/help/20/en) or [google drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2424384?hl=en) possible??

Comment: @heavyd: thanks, i didn't think about that, probably it would...

Comment: @MikePennington: if it's such a security risk, I will consider it. Don't have any file hosting accounts yet. Hosting 50 GB seems not for free.

Comment: To increase security of FTP server mentioned in answer from Spiff, the default ftp port 21 can be changed to another value xxxx, which would only be known to the intended people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the manual for your EA6700, Linksys intended SMB (Windows-style file sharing) to only be used on the LAN, and provided FTP server support for WAN-side access to files on the USB disks attached to the gateway.

If FTP access suits your needs, just enable the FTP server.

(FTP is great for downloading and uploading full files, but it's not really meant for treating the server's storage like it's a local disk. So it's not great at editing files directly on the server, or just reading or writing parts of a file, or for streaming audio or video. SMB is designed for treating the remote disk as local, so it's fine for editing files directly on the server, reading/writing parts of a file, and it's okay for streaming although most purpose-built streaming protocols would be better at streaming.)

If you ever expose an SMB server to the Internet, be aware that the SMB-related ports are some of the most-attacked ports on the Internet. Make sure that all the accounts that are enabled on the SMB server host have extremely strong passwords, as you can expect automatic brute-force password crackers to be running against your service. Also beware that at times, SMB-cracking malware has been such a problem that some ISPs by default block access to SMB-related ports for typical residential broadband service, so if SMB doesn't work, you might want to check with your ISP to get those ports unblocked.

SSH and FTP ports are also quite likely to be attacked, so be sure to have extremely strong passwords everywhere, even if you choose to provide file access via FTP or SCP instead of SMB.

Comment: To increase security of FTP server, the default ftp port 21 can be changed to another value xxxx, which would only be known to the intended people.

Answer (score 0):

If your need is to allow people to download files and there is no need for authentication, then I would get a small board (like a Raspberry Pi) for 35 €. Plug your disk to it. I would install a Linux on it, run a web server like Nginx or Apache Web Server or Lighttpd, set the Linux firewall to only allow the port on which your web server is running, plug the board to your router and either do one of the following:

- Set the board IP address to the DMZ; or
- (my preferred solution) set port forwarding on the router to redirect an external port to the internal port of your board.

Why such a solution? It is much easier to secure properly a HTTP server than an FTP server, and you do not need to manage accounts for giving access to files. In addition, it is much easier to setup good "jails" to simple HTTP server like that so that a malicious user cannot do much more than downloading the files you offered. Finally, the standard HTTP (80) and HTTPS (443) ports are extremely rarely blocked by ISP.

If you get the Raspberry Pi, simply install the [Noobs installer](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/), it is really easy to install a Linux that way (choose Raspbian when prompted). Then installing a web server is also a no brainer (check this example to [install nginx](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/nginx.md)), configuring is a little bit [more complex](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/web-server/). The firewall part is a [bit more tricky](http://www.heystephenwood.com/2013/06/setting-up-firewall-on-your-raspberry-pi.html) if you've never done it, and if you use port forwarding (instead of the DMZ) it is a step you could skip for later, as your router would do most of the firewalling.

Finally, you should try to see if your ISP provides you with a static IP address or dynamic. If it is static, simply buy a domain name or just use the IP address to let people download your files. If it is dynamic IP address, use one of the numerous DDNS services, those are DNS services that work with dynamic IP addresses, it is probably that your Linksys router offers DDNS settings. Note that some DDNS services might requires some charges.